# Building DLL file in C++ Netbeans

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans

I am trying to build the following in Netbean using c++. However I am unable to do so. I receive the following error.

> gcc -shared -m32    -o dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
>   build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/JNIDemo.o  -mno-cygwin -shared gcc: error:
>   unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-cygwin’

I am only able to build this manually using the following command

> gcc -shared -o dist/libJNIDemoCdl.so
>   build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/JNIDemo.o -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_
>   -Wl,--kill-at

How do I fix this issue with the netbean IDE?

## Header file

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jnidemojava_Main */

#ifndef _Included_jnidemojava_Main
#define _Included_jnidemojava_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jnidemojava_Main
 * Method:    nativePrint
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

## Source

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "JNIDemoJava.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_nativePrint
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

    printf("\nHello World from C\n");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin and gcc removed the deprecated support of -mno-cygwin flag.
It seems you are using and old version of gcc, update your gcc version to  GCC >=4.3

Or follow [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/toolchain.html) and remove -mno-cygwin flag manually from your builtin toolchain descriptors